# Pandas - Merge dataframes with 'Indifferent' values

Tags: python, pandas, merge

Is it possible to make dataframes with values that mean 'Indifferent'?
If so how do you merge them so they return all possibilities? The code below makes 2 dataframes and merges them (the None value for Number of Wedding Venues in dataframe right should mean 'Indifferent'):

```
import pandas as pd
left = pd.DataFrame({'Religion': ['Islam', 'Christianity', 'Judaism', 'None'], 'Number of Wedding Venues': [2, 2, 2, 1]})
right = pd.DataFrame({'Number of Wedding Venues': [None, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1], 'Transportation': ['Old Timer', 'Bus', 'Motorcycle', 'Limousine', 'Motorcycle', 'Old Timer', 'Limousine']})

merged = left.merge(right, on='Number of Wedding Venues', how='outer')

Left
       Religion  Number of Wedding Venues
0         Islam                         2
1  Christianity                         2
2       Judaism                         2
3          None                         1

Right
   Number of Wedding Venues Transportation
0                       NaN      Old Timer
1                       2.0            Bus
2                       1.0     Motorcycle
3                       2.0      Limousine
4                       1.0     Motorcycle
5                       2.0      Old Timer
6                       1.0      Limousine

Merged
            Religion  Number of Wedding Venues Transportation
0          Islam                       2.0            Bus
1          Islam                       2.0      Limousine
2          Islam                       2.0      Old Timer
3   Christianity                       2.0            Bus
4   Christianity                       2.0      Limousine
5   Christianity                       2.0      Old Timer
6        Judaism                       2.0            Bus
7        Judaism                       2.0      Limousine
8        Judaism                       2.0      Old Timer
9           None                       1.0     Motorcycle
10          None                       1.0     Motorcycle
11          None                       1.0      Limousine
12           NaN                       NaN      Old Timer
```

My problem is with line 12. If for example I now say that all rows for which column Religion = Islam should be deleted, it will not delete row 12 even though it's not right. What I am really asking is: Would it be possible for row 12 to look like this (and thus that pandas has a word for 'Indifferent'):

```
Islam                        2            Old Timer
Christianity                 2            Old Timer
Judaism                      2            Old Timer
None                         1            Old Timer
```

Comment: "Indifferent" is not a technical term. Your intent is not clear.

Comment: With indifferent I mean that is doesn't matter which value it takes. In this case it could be both 1 or 2

Comment: Use groupby after the merge. Then you can apply functions to the columns e.g. first/any for columns where any value from the group is OK.